# Trying to paint a polygon on a graphics view, but have a problem getting the coordinates from inside the graphics view

Tags: qt, qt6

I have a mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h file, a ui file containing the graphicsview. I load an image into a QGraphicsPixmapItem from a QImage. I add that pixmapitem named 'item' to a scene. And i set the scene with the following ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);. I have a zoom out, a zoom in button and a fit to window button.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionZoom_In_triggered()
{
    ui->graphicsView->scale(1.25,1.25);
    //item->update(1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25);
    //scene->update(1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionZoom_Out_triggered()
{
    ui->graphicsView->scale(0.75,0.75);
    //item->update(0.75,0.75,0.75,07.5);
    //scene->update(0.75,0.75,0.75,07.5);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionFit_Window_triggered()
{
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

To get a point i use `QPointF point = ui->graphicsView->mapFromParent(event->pos());`

This only work when the image has not been zoomed out, zoomed in or fitted to window.

I have the feeling that it gets the points/coordinates from the situation when the image originally loaded. So the graphicsview scales, the item scales (i think), but i have the idea that the scene doesn't.

Either i want to call the method mousePressEvent from QGraphicsView (because that may work) or have the area from where the coordinates are collected from enlarged.

Steps:

1. [Loading Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHxW3.png)
2. [Drawing Polygon (Picture not transformed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBWO8.png)
3. [Wrong coordinates, still in original area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXu8Y.png)